# Merge X-numbers of JSON into one JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have several Ajax-requests that retrieves data from the server... 
I want to add them together, so I can use the data set later.

This is how one JSON-looks like:

```
{
   "51" : { id:"51", name:"frank" },
   "52" : { id:"52", name:"jonny" }
}
```

A second later there might come another one, with the exactly the same structure. How do I just "append" a new json into this to make a large object with the same structure..

EG: (append like this)

```
{
   "51" : { id:"51", name:"frank" },
   "52" : { id:"52", name:"jonny" },
   "72" : { id:"72", name:"daniel"},
   "73" : { id:"73", name:"lisa"},
   "74" : { id:"74", name:"ida"},
   "75" : { id:"75", name:"ali"}       
}
```

Comment: Only jQuery can do that, it does all things. Here you'd use `$.extend`

Comment: @adeneo jQuery is just [the Emacs of JS](https://xkcd.com/378/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the ID will always be unique, you can do something like:

```
var buffer = {};

messageSource.on('message', function (msg) {
    var msgKeys = Object.keys(msg); // Get the list of IDs
    msgKeys.forEach(function (key) { // For each numeric key...
        buffer[key] = msg[key]; // Copy the message
    });
});
```

If you cannot guarantee unique IDs, you'll need some minor changes:

```
var buffer = {};

messageSource.on('message', function (msg) {
    var msgKeys = Object.keys(msg);
    msgKeys.forEach(function (key) {
        buffer[key] = (buffer[key] || []).push(msg[key]); // Only change, append to list for that key
    });
});
```

Comment: You, sir..saved the day! +1 for messageSource

Answer (score -1):

You should use Jquery [$.merge](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/):

```
var obj1 = {
   "51" : { id:"51", name:"frank" },
   "52" : { id:"52", name:"jonny" }
};

var obj2 = {
   "72" : { id:"72", name:"daniel"},
   "73" : { id:"73", name:"lisa"},
   "74" : { id:"74", name:"ida"},
   "75" : { id:"75", name:"ali"}       
}

var result =  $.extend(obj1, obj2);
```

Working exemple [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzdky1xd/)

Comment: OP didn't ask for jQuery or show themselves using it, so suggesting it in answers is generally frowned upon.